# Very difficult to drag image icons around the desktop in OS X 10.12.6

Tags: preview, desktop, ui

I have a OS X 10.12.6 recent MacBook Pro.  On a previous version of the OS, if I had an image file on the desktop, it was easy to grab the icon with the mouse and drag it onto another application.  Now (I think when I upgraded to 10.12.6), such a drag action is very difficult: it only occasionally works, and most of the time as I start to drag there is an additional trackpad-depress sensation and a quick preview pops out of the icon.  Here's a screenshot of such a preview:

[image: Screenshot of an image preview]

**Question**: What is this new preview feature called, and is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ‘preview’ is Quick Look, a feature released in 2007, originally activated through pressing space on the keyboard (not to be confused with [preview](/questions/tagged/preview) the app). In addition to space, activating it through Force Touch on the trackpad has been around since the introduction of Force Touch. Not that I'm saying you haven't had this problem before, but the feature isn't new with 10.12.6.

It's possible you've stumbled on a bug with that version of macOS, where the Force Touch sensitivity or drag-detection is failing. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

You can completely disable Force Click in System Preferences → Trackpad → Point & Click by unchecking Force Click and haptic feedback.

Comment: Excellent, being careful to press lightly seems to work well enough.